# Azure BlobStorage stream is closed on files > 25 MB

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, c#-ziparchive

I'm storing some large files in a Blog Storage Container.

Later, using a WebJob (also in Azure), I read from each of these blobs using `CloudBlockBlob.OpenRead()` that gives me a `Stream`.

I open the stream and read from it. 
The problem is that when the file is larger than 25 MB aprox., after some time reading OK, it throws this exception (during a read):

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while
>   copying content to a stream. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException:
>   Cannot access a closed Stream.     at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
>   at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Position() at
>   System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.StartAsync()

It seems that the file is closed on the other side!

Why does this happen? Is there a timeout? How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your connection speed, your response may be timing out. This would support your statement that it is for files of **about** 25MB. Increase the `ServerTimeout` and/or `MaximumExecutionTime` using [BlobRequestOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.aspx) to resolve.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not downloading the file, but opening a stream from it using cloudBlobBlock.OpenRead(). This is a by requirement.

Comment: Have you tried setting BlobRequestOptions ServerTimeout and Maximum execution time?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions_members(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: It works! using OpenRead with these options: return block.OpenRead(null, new BlobRequestOptions()
            {
                ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 4),                
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
            });

Answer (score 0):

I've invoked the OpenRead() method with these options and it seems it no longer times out!

```
return block.OpenRead(null, new BlobRequestOptions()
            {
                ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 4),                
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
            });
```